# Vue 3 / Express params returning their name

Tags: node.js, express, axios

First off let me say sorry if the title of the question confused anyone reading my question. I didn't know how to best word my question. The issue I'm having is when I try to send a get request from my axios instance to my express instance. When I send data from axios, I have my object showing all the data it needs but when I try to utilize that data in express using `req.params.email` the value its holding is `:email` heres my code:

**Client/Axios**

```
  checkEmail (data) {
    return http.get('/users/:email', data)
  },
```

**Value of 'data' Object**

```
{email: 'ThisIs@MyEmail.Org'}
```

**Server/Express**

```
  router.get('/users/:email', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.email)
    const data = User.find({ email: req.params.email })
    return res.sendStatus(200).json(data)
  })
```

**Server Console Log**

```
{ email: ':email' }
```

As a side note I have tried to just use `req.params` but it returns the same thing. If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Just do `http.get('/users/ThisIs@MyEmail.Org')`. The second parameter to `http.get` is for options, not URL parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  code will works.
You needs to switch from `hard code data`

to your `const data = User.find({ email: req.params.email })`

From

```
    const data = {
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        first_name: 'Tom',
        last_name: 'Cruise'
    }
```

To

```
    const data = User.find({ email: req.params.email  })
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.get("/users/:email", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("params", req.params);
    // const data = User.find({ email: req.params.email  })
    const data = {
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        first_name: 'Tom',
        last_name: 'Cruise'
    }
    res.status(200).json(data);
});

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log("Listening on :3000") })
```

client.js

```
const axios = require('axios')
const checkEmail = async (data) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${data}`);
        return Promise.resolve(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
};

checkEmail('ThisIs@MyEmail.Org')
    .then(result => {
        console.log('user is : ' + JSON.stringify(result))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
    });
```

Install dependencies

```
npm install express axios cors
```

Run first server

```
node server.js
```

Run second client

```
node client.js
```

Result at server

[image]

Result at client

[image]